# jQuery is not return output in console

Tags: html, jquery, django, console

I was building a ecom platform in Django so I wanted to make a function that whenever I click on my add to cart button the console will return the product number. That is why I wrote this jQuery at the very end of my index.html file but it's not working.
Should I download jQuery for this? Because CDN is not working on my computer.

```
{% extends 'shop/basic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block css %}
    .col-md-3 {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: -4px;
    }

    .carousel-indicators .active {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .col-md-3 img {
        width: 227px;
        max-height: 242px;
    }

    body .carousel-indicator li {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    body .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: 0;
    }

    body .carousel-control-prev-icon,
    body .carousel-control-next-icon {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev,
    .carousel-control-next {
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    body .no-padding {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <!-- First Carousel -->
    {% for product, range, nSlides in allProds %}
    <h3 class="my-4">Flash Sale On {{ product.0.category }} - Recommended Items</h3>
    <div id="demo{{ forloop.counter }}" class="carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#demo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            {% for i in range %}
            <li data-target="#demo{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}" data-slide-to="{{ i }}"></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src='/media/{{ product.0.image }}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.0.product_name }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ product.0.desc }}</p>
                            <button id="pr{{ product.0.id }}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% for i in product|slice:"1:"%}
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src='/media/{{ i.image }}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ i.product_name }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ i.desc }}</p>
                            <button id="pr{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and Right controls for the first carousel -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- Second Carousel -->
    {% for product, range, nSlides in anotherProds %}
    <h5 class="my-4">New Arrivals - {{ product.0.category }}</h5>
    <div id="anotherDemo{{ forloop.counter }}" class="carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#anotherDemo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            {% for i in range %}
            <li data-target="#anotherDemo{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}" data-slide-to="{{ i }}"></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src='/media/{{ product.0.image }}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.0.product_name }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ product.0.desc }}</p>
                            <button id="pr{{ product.0.id }}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% for i in product|slice:"1:"%}
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src='/media/{{ i.image }}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ i.product_name }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ i.desc }}</p>
                            <button id="pr{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and Right controls for the second carousel -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#anotherDemo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#anotherDemo{{ forloop.counter }}" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    console.log('working')
    if(localStorage.getItem('cart') == null)
    {
    var cart={};
    }
    else{
    cart= JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('cart'));
    }
    //jQuery starts here//
    $('.cart').click(function(){

        console.log('clicked');
        var idstr= this.id.toString();
        console.log(idstr);
        if(cart[idstr]!= undefined) {
        cart[idstr] = cart[idstr]+1;
        }
        else{
        cart[idstr] = 1;
        }
        console.log(cart);
        });
    </script>
{% endblock%}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: No but I am not getting the product number here

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML and not your server-side code. JavaScript in the browser doesn't care what's on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable called cart if localStorage is not null, so you can try this:

```
console.log('working')
var cart = {};
if (localStorage.getItem('cart') != null) {
  cart = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('cart'));
}
$('.cart').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  var idstr = this.id.toString();
  console.log(idstr);
  if (cart[idstr] != undefined) {
    cart[idstr] = cart[idstr] + 1;
  } else {
    cart[idstr] = 1;
  }
  console.log(cart);
});
```

Comment: No sir still I am having the same problem